# User-Roles missing after login on Glassfish JDBC-Realm

Tags: authentication, jakarta-ee, jdbc, glassfish, jdbcrealm

I have a jdbc-realm configured on Glassfish and i am trying to implement authentication for users with multiple roles. I am using JPA to manage the database tables, JDK 1.7, Glassfish3+, and EclipseLink (JPA 2.0).

I already can successfully login using FORM based authentication, but as a logged-in user i dont have any of the defined roles assigned.

My entity mapping on the relevant classes is

**PersonAccount.java:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PersonAccount") 
public class PersonAccount implements Serializable {

@Id
@NotNull
private String userName;       
private String passwordHash;        

@ManyToMany(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST})
private Set<UserRole> userRoles = new HashSet<UserRole>();;

...
```

**UserRole.java:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="UserRole") 
public class UserRole extends NamedEntity implements Serializable {

@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
private persons.util.RoleType roleType = RoleType.StudentRole;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy="userRoles", cascade=
    {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE})
private Set<PersonAccount> personAccounts = new HashSet<PersonAccount>(); 

...
```

where the base class NamedEntity defines a primary key "id" and a value "name", and "PersonAccount" itself is assigned to a "Person".

When creating the first (master admin) account "admin admin" the content of my database looks like this:

```
PERSONACCOUNT:
.USERNAME = admin
.PASSWORDHASH = 8c6976e5b5410415bde908bd4dee15dfb167a9c873fc4bb8a81f6f2ab448a918
.PERSON_ID = 220002

PERSONACCOUNT_USERROLE:
.PERSONACCOUNTS_USERNAME admin
.USERROLES_ID = 220001

USERROLE:
.ID = 220001
.NAME = AdminRole
.ROLETYPE = 3
```

After creating the account i can login with form-based authentication. The principal-name returned is "admin", but none of the user-roles "AdminRole", "FacultyRole", "TeacherRole" or "StudentRole" is assigned. This i can verify by trying to access one of the security protected pages.

Here the configurations of my application and glassfish:

**web.xml:**

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>klops</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/login.xhtml?error=true</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
<security-role>
    <description>Administrators</description>
    <role-name>AdminRole</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role>
    <description>Faculty</description>
    <role-name>FacultyRole</role-name>
</security-role>    
<security-role>
    <description>Teachers</description>
    <role-name>TeacherRole</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role>
    <description>Students</description>
    <role-name>StudentRole</role-name>
</security-role>
```

**glassfish-web.xml**

```
<security-role-mapping>
    <principal-name>admin</principal-name>      
    <role-name>AdminRole</role-name>
    <group-name>AdminRole</group-name>
</security-role-mapping>
<security-role-mapping>
    <principal-name>teacher</principal-name>
    <role-name>TeacherRole</role-name>
    <group-name>TeacherRole</group-name>
</security-role-mapping>
<security-role-mapping>
    <role-name>StudentRole</role-name>
    <group-name>StudentRole</group-name>
    <principal-name>student</principal-name>
</security-role-mapping>
<security-role-mapping>
    <principal-name>faculty</principal-name>
    <role-name>FacultyRole</role-name>
    <group-name>FacultyRole</group-name>
</security-role-mapping>
```

And finally, the realm configuration:

```
    <auth-realm name="myjdbcrealm" classname="com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.jdbc.JDBCRealm">
      <property name="jaas-context" value="jdbcRealm"></property>
      <property name="password-column" value="passwordhash"></property>
      <property name="assign-groups" value="AdminRole,FacultyRole,TeacherRole,StudentRole"></property>
      <property name="datasource-jndi" value="jdbc/__default"></property>
      <property name="user-table" value="personaccount"></property>
      <property name="group-table" value="userrole"></property>
      <property name="user-name-column" value="username"></property>
      <property name="group-name-column" value="name"></property>
      <property name="digest-algorithm" value="SHA-256"></property>
    </auth-realm>
```

I am kind of baffled by the fact that some of the information is found (i can only login with the created account, and only with the correct password), but when im logged in, the user context does not seem to possess any roles.

I have searched everywhere and tried for nearly a day now, but i cannot find the error here.
It would even help to be able to list the roles a connected user has at the moment, but it seems the only way to check for a role is by knowing its name using

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().
    isUserInRole("AdminRole"));
```

Help on this problem would be greatly appreciated :)

Thanks,

Patrick

**EDIT:**

I created a view USER_ACCOUNTS which contains UserRole.name as UserName and PersonAccount_Userrole.username as UserName and changed the realm mapping accordingly, but i still get the same results.
If the username equals the principal-name in the security role mapping, the user has all of the 4 roles. If i remove the principal-name from the mapping the user has no roles at all after logging in.

Now tables contents and configuration are:

```
PERSONACCOUNT: (Table)
.USERNAME = admin
.PASSWORDHASH = 8c6976e5b5410415bde908bd4dee15dfb167a9c873fc4bb8a81f6f2ab448a918
.PERSON_ID = 220002

USER_ACCOUNTS: (View)
.USERNAME = admin
.ROLENAME = AdminRole
```

and

```
  <property name="password-column" value="passwordhash"></property>
  <property name="assign-groups" value="AdminRole,FacultyRole,TeacherRole,StudentRole"></property>
  <property name="user-table" value="personaccount"></property>
  <property name="group-table" value="user_accounts"></property>
  <property name="user-name-column" value="username"></property>
  <property name="group-name-column" value="rolename"></property>
  <property name="digest-algorithm" value="SHA-256"></property>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your `auth-realm` definition (which I'm assuming is valid for the moment), I'd expect to see two tables (with minimum information similar to):

```
CREATE TABLE `personaccount` (
  `username` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `passwordhash` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`username`)
);

CREATE TABLE `userrole` (
  `username` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL, -- role name
  PRIMARY KEY (`username`,`name`) -- allow multiple roles per user
);
```

Note that the `username` column has the same (column) name in both tables.

---

I see that you have three tables:

```
PERSONACCOUNT
PERSONACCOUNT_USERROLE
USERROLE
```

If you want to preserve that structure, then create a `view` to map the `PERSONACCOUNT_USERROLE` and `USERROLE` tables into something looks like the group table shown above, and make that view your `group-table`.

I can confirm that this view-based strategy works with Glassfish 3.1.X and MySQL; it may not be portable to other app-servers.

---

Not sure what you're trying to accomplish with your `security-role-mapping` including the principal name, other than possibly trying to work around the missing roles from the JDBC Realm.

---

Likewise, the purpose of the realm property `assign-groups` is to establish a set of groups that are always defined for all users.  I gather from your later comments this behavior was unexpected; this is apparently the cause.

Comment: I used the three tables because thats what was done in the tutorial, so i thought it should work. But ok, now i created a view "User_Account" which contains "RoleName" from table userrole and "UserName" from personaccount_userrole. But i get the same results. Logging in is possible. If the username equals the principal name the user has all four roles. If i remove the <principal-name> definition from the <security-role-mapping> the user has no roles after logging in.

Comment: Can you confirm that anything in the realm is working?  Specifically, it rejects unknown users and wrong passwords?

Comment: Yes, everything seems to work fine. Incorrect passwords are rejected and unknown users are rejected. When logged in, the correct username is returned by getRemoteUser(). When logged in with the specified principal name "admin", a user has all of the roles, and i can access all of the security protected pages. If i remove the principal name the user has no roles and he cannot access them (Error 403). So it seems that the role mapping is the only thing that does not work.

Comment: @PatrickGeib update related to use of assign-groups realm property; you may want to just drop that property.

Comment: It works!!! Without the assign-groups, WITH specified principal names, and after restarting the server, now it works! I still dont know why exactly, but ill find out eventually. Started with JavaEE only a few days ago xD Thanks a whole lot Richard, you are a lifesaver :) If i should reach the 15 Rep score ill give you "useful"-ups for that one too :)